# Mongoose .findOne not working as an internal function call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With this as a URL:

> **'api/support-tag/name/myTagName'**

This function works properly:

```
    getByName: function (req, res) {
    model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name: req.params.name}).exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errMsg.Util_ErrorMsg.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        res.send(results);
    })
}
```

But when I try to call a similar function from within the node server:

```
supportDoc.category = GetById(item.category);

function GetById(name){
    model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name: name}).exec(function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
}
```

The function does not execute, nor does the error catch, intellisense shows:

```
 err= Reference error; err is not defined

 result = Reference error; result is not defined
```

All I am trying to accomplish is a function call from within the server and not via a URL.

Any solution here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
  model.Shared_SupportDoc.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
                var supportDocs = require('../../data/_seed/support/supportDocs.json');
                if (collection.length === 0) {
                    supportDocs.forEach(function (item) {
                        var supportDoc = new model.Shared_SupportDoc;
                        supportDoc.title = item.title;
                        supportDoc.created = item.date;
                        supportDoc.icon = item.icon;
                        supportDoc.likeCount = item.likeCount || 7;

  ----->   // requires callback - ie asynchronous
            GetByName(item.category, function(tagId) {
                supportDoc.categoryId = tagId;

      ----->   // must put save in the callback
                supportDoc.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(supportDoc.categoryId)
                        console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Support Doc Seed Complete');
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    }
});}


 function GetByName(name, next) {
   model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name : name}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (!result) {
        console.log('Not Found');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log(result._id);
        next(result._id);
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `findOne()` method, the positive response (sans error) will either hold a mongoose object or null.

If the same query had been sent using just `find()`, the result would have been an empty array.

```
function GetById(name){
    model.Shared_SupportTag.findOne({name: name}).exec(function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            if (result) console.log(result); //Check whether object exists.
            else console.log('Not found!');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: That did not work, still got back 'undefined' as a value